# How do I get Automatic Updates to work (problem) (clarification)

Tags: updates, automatic

Sorry my question was too cryptic :-(
I'm running Ubuntu 21.10
I'm getting a banner message:
"Automatic Updates Paused", with a button,[Find Out More]. This opens dialogue box with a button [Open Network Settings] but the link is dead.
I think the auto updates are paused when on a metered connection, which I'm not (though it is a mobile Wi-Fi router). I've checked > Settings, > Wi-Fi > Router [Settings]. The "Metered connection" check-box is blank.
What to do?

Comment: How does it report this? A message a screen showing this what?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing the unattended-upgrades apt package via the command line:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

To verify automatic updates are running:

```
systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service
```

Comment: I do not see how this is going to work based on the error the OP is giving. Can you give more details?

Comment: The supplied error wasn't very specific, so i thought if its just automatic updates he wants, installing unattendend-upgrades might be a simple solution